# How can I add one pcl Pointcloud_xyzrgb to another?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can I add one PCL Pointcloud (xyzrgb) to another?
I tried to use "+=" as described in the docu, but it didn't work.
Any ideas?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63757/how-can-i-add-one-pcl-pointcloud_xyzrgb-to-another?/) by [Seba](https://answers.ros.org/users/5005/seba/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-05-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That definitely works for me. Are you absolutely sure you're using two pointclouds of the same type? Can you edit your post with the error you're getting?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-05-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0